# PHP Dom Parser to get span value

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm looking to gather information from an external URL, and strip it to just the value.

For example

```
<span id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserStatisticsPane_lFriendsStatistics">149</span>
```

I can't find a way to use PHP Dom to get '149'

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around would be to use `preg_match()`, but I only would use it with curl()...

```
$row = '<span id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserStatisticsPane_lFriendsStatistics">149</span>';
preg_match_all('/<span.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*span>/s', $row, $matches2);
var_dump($matches2);
```

Another option is to use simple_html_dom.php:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($row);

var_dump($html->find('span', 0)->plaintext);
```

And the third one would be to use built in DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DOMRemove(DOMNode $from) {
    $sibling = $from->firstChild;
    do {
        $next = $sibling->nextSibling;
        $from->parentNode->insertBefore($sibling, $from);
    } while ($sibling = $next);
    $from->parentNode->removeChild($from);    
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('test.html');

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    DOMRemove($node);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663865/1675369

- Also: There's a library to parse HTML for PHP. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/